# Validity of Naturalisation Test (Einbürgerungstest)

Tags: germany, citizenship, eu-citizens, german-citizens, nationality

I want to give the German Einbürgerungstest (naturalisation or citizenship test) but I could not find any information regarding the validity of the results.

Does the test certificate have an expiration date?

For how many months or years is the test result valid? Can I still use it if I'm applying for the citizenship after 1.5 years let's say.

Comment: It is valid until as long as humans exist (for now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The naturalization test itself is **not associated with a validity**.

- Passing a naturalization test is *sufficient* proof of knowledge of the FRG’s legal system, society and living conditions, § 10 Ⅴ 1 StAG.
  This is assessed via a catalog of questions.
  The questions are found in the [EinbTestV](http://Bundesrecht.Juris.de/einbtestv).
  As long as the EinbTestV remains unchanged, the FRG’s makeup at its core has not diverged too much either.
  Thus:

  Considering the last amendment of the EinbTestV became effective on April Fool’s Day 2013, passing the naturalization test on 2013‑04‑01 or on 2023‑06‑26 makes no difference with respect to tested knowledge.
  The **question catalog is still the same**.
- However, humans tend to forget stuff.
  As of today (2023‑06‑24) nationality laws are completely ignorant of any “decay” in human memory.
  Case in point, once you have been naturalized, you will never have to prove sufficient knowledge again.
  You will never be stripped German citizenship just because you have forgotten some details.
  Sufficient knowledge merely has to be **proven at a single point in time**.
- Specifically you will need to prove sufficient knowledge *when filing your naturalization application*, not earlier, not later.
  And here is the catch.
  Today’s legal basis for naturalization is § 10 Ⅰ StAG.
  This law may be amended any day.
  Today it does not contain any qualification with respect to the naturalization test’s date; tomorrow it could.

  The naturalization test itself is not an administrative act (*Verwaltungsakt*, § 35 S. 1 VwVfG), thus there is also no protection of legitimate expectation (*Vertrauensschutz*).
  Only if you **file your naturalization application *today*** you have a certain protected legitimate expectation that your eligibility is assessed based on today’s laws.